# How to identify apps requesting to control the computer under Accessibility

Tags: macos, assistive-technology

I currently have this "applet" listed as being able to control my computer. Is there a way to identify exactly what this is?

[image: screenshot of Accessibility section]

Comment: I would guess a Java applet that is not properly named?

Comment: @tubedogg that was my guess as well. I have this Java applet installed for printing on my university's network called "PaperCut NG", and I suspected that was it, but I'd like to be certain.